# two form controls of same type and class are showing up in different sizes

Tags: razor

I am working on cshtml page which has two textboxes like below

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control input-lg" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control input-lg" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReturnToken)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

but above text boxes are appearingin two different sizes like in below image.
[image]

**Seems like the sizes are varying because of max and min length in the model. How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the following div in both instances. This will resize the form controls to go full width.

```
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">...</div>
```